# CakePHP Links and Tags

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, tags

I'm using CakePHP. So far I cannot combine the paragraph tags and CakePHP links in one line. The link keeps on printing in another line.

So far I've tried these:

```
<?php
    $arr = array('<p>Please download the file ', $this->Html->link('here', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'download')), '</p>');
    echo join(" ", $arr);
?>

<?php echo '<p>Please download the file ' .  $this->Html->link('here', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'download')) . '</p>'; ?>
```

Comment: Whats your expected result?

Comment: The result is always the link getting printed in another line.

Comment: i hope your css breaks it.. U ran your code in my cakphp script and it works fine.. So please check whether your css set width or equivalent for the elemnt.

Comment: I doubt it's my CSS. I didn't use any 'id' or 'class' elements.

Comment: you may not use.. But it can be controlled by parent element. If a span inside a div can be controlled by the div properties. Use your firebug.

Answer (score 0):

For the paragraph (or any other HTML tag for that matter), you can use the [tag method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::tag) of the HtmlHelper. Put them together like this:

```
echo $this->Html->tag('p',
    'Please download the file ' .
    $this->Html->link('here', array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'download'
    ))
);
```